xterm.js generates full row of characters before writeln output
While experimenting with xterm.js I made the follwing fiddle.
const divTerm = document.querySelector("#term");

const xterm = new Terminal({
cols: 100,
rows: 80,
cursorBlink: true
});

xterm.open(divTerm);
xterm.writeln("Hello World");


As you can see, I am only writing "Hello World" to my terminal.
However, the "Hello World" String is only displayed on the second row of the terminal. The row above is filled with 'd's, and I don't understand where they are coming from.
The weird thing is, when I did the same thing on my test site instead on jsfiddle, the behaviour was the same, except the first row was filled with 's' characters.
What's going on here?

I discovered that it's always the last character of the String, that is repeated in the row above

What you see here, is the visual repr of the char measurement. You miss the xterm.css file to hide that.
